# SQL SERVER IF ELSE

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a query running in PHP that is supposed to detect of the record is already in the database and if it is update it else insert it, this query works great when it's inserting data, however i think when it's updating it gives me this error.

> SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion
>   failed when converting date and/or time from character string., SQL
>   state 22008 in SQLExecDirect

Im not sure why it would do this as the data is the exact same as the insert data which works fine Why would this be?

```
IF EXISTS
(SELECT count(DocumentNo) AS COUNT
FROM SalesOrders
WHERE (DocumentNo = '$OrderNo'))
UPDATE SalesOrders
SET RequestedDeliveryDate ='$RequestDelivery',
SupplierDocumentNo ='$SupplierDocumentNo',
SupplierAccountName = '$SupplierAccountName',
DispatchName ='$DispatchName'
WHERE (DocumentDate = '$OrderNo') ELSE
INSERT INTO SalesOrders (DocumentNo, DocumentDate,  CustomerAccountName,PostalName, RequestedDeliveryDate, SupplierDocumentNo, SupplierAccountName,DispatchName)
VALUES ('$OrderNo',
      '$OrderDate',
      '$AccountName',
      '$PostalName',
      '$RequestDelivery',
      '$SupplierDocumentNo',
      '$SupplierAccountName',
      '$DispatchName')
```

Table design

```
    Column Name Data Type   Allow Null
    ID  int Unchecked
    DocumentNo  varchar(50) Checked
    DocumentDate    date    Checked
    CustomerAccountName varchar(100)    Checked
    PostalName  varchar(100)    Checked
    RequestedDeliveryDate   date    Checked
    ShipmentType    varchar(50) Checked
    Shipped int Checked
    Collected   int Checked
    OrderComplete   tinyint Checked
    SupplierDocumentNo  varchar(100)    Checked
    SupplierAccountName varchar(100)    Checked
    DispatchName    varchar(100)    Checked
    HiddenStatus    int Checked
```

query result that is used to feed the insert/update query

```
    DocumentNo  DocumentDate    CustomerAccountName RequestedDeliveryDate   PostalName  SupplierDocumentNo  SupplierAccountName Name
    233555      05/03/2015      CompanyName             16/04/2015      CompanyName NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233531      04/03/2015      CompanyName             13/04/2015      CompanyName NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233475      02/03/2015      CompanyName             09/04/2015      NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233561      05/03/2015      CompanyName             07/04/2015      CompanyName NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233474      02/03/2015      CompanyName             02/04/2015      NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233379      24/02/2015      CompanyName             31/03/2015      NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233383      24/02/2015      CompanyName             31/03/2015      NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233387      24/02/2015      CompanyName             31/03/2015      NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233391      24/02/2015      CompanyName             31/03/2015      NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233397      24/02/2015      CompanyName             31/03/2015      NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233401      24/02/2015      CompanyName             31/03/2015      NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233404      24/02/2015      CompanyName             31/03/2015      NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233408      24/02/2015      CompanyName             31/03/2015      NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
    233412      24/02/2015      CompanyName             31/03/2015      NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but could you just provide the exact value of `$RequestDelivery` that makes the query fail?

Comment: The values in the example data are the exact values, the function in php loops through each result and then does the update/insert depending if it's there already or not

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to see what command is being sent to SQL Server when it errors.   Maybe the reason for the error will then be obvious.